# Stripe custom button

Tags: stripe-payments

so I am trying to integrate stripe checkout button (beta version that get's you to a Stripe checkout page) the problem is that the button is gray and plain and wasn't able to change size or color or format it in general.

I don't have any coding skills, I have tried to use a CSS custom button but not sure how can I link this to the original code.

So I appreciate if anyone could help me to either:

Have the ability to link the outcome of clicking on the stripe original button to one of my buttons OR

Help me format the button, by increasing it's size, using a specific font and choosing a color so that I can modify them myself.

Thanks a lot in advance

This is the code I am using:

```
<!-- Load Stripe.js on your website. -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>

<!-- Create a button that your customers click to complete their purchase. -->
<button id="checkout-button">StandardBlue</button>
<div id="error-message"></div>

<script>
  var stripe = Stripe('KEYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY', {
    betas: ['checkout_beta_3']
  });

  var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
    // them to Checkout.
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{sku: 'SKU', quantity: 1}],
      successUrl: 'https://WEBSITE.COM/success',
      cancelUrl: 'https://WEBSITE.COM/canceled',
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. You should consider using professional coding services

Comment: You might find a tutorial like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works a good place to start with CSS. For Stripe's default button style, it's a bit of a hack but  https://mattarkin.com/pretty-custom-integration-stripe-button/. Best wishes!

Comment: ^ This doesn't work. You still get the original button. So you would have to write some js to remove it from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple here. Just add css with the selector #checkout-button.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/tonyprovenzola/sb7dtakz/3/

```
button#checkout-button {
font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
padding:10px 14px;
background-color:#255eba;
border-radius:10px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
border:none;
outline:none;
}

button#checkout-button:hover {
background-color:#112a51;
}
```